# HTML - CSS - Horizontal UL's floated list-item not moving to next line and takes space between two lines

Tags: html, css

This is my HTML with a simple horizontal UL with left floated list items:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<style>
ul li { 
    float:left; 
    padding: 5px; 
    list-style: none 
}
</style>

<ul style="width: 607px;">
  <li><a>Home</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>Contact us</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1 copy</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1 coopy</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1 co.lpoooy</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1 co.o..y</a></li>
  <li></li>
  <li><a>P1 ...y</a></li>
  <li style="height:17px">A</li>
  <li><a>|</a></li>
  <li><a><span>John Doe</span></a></li>
 </ul>

</body>
</html>
```

As shown in the browser view below, one of the list items (the one with pipe "|") doesn't stay with first line nor it goes to next line (where John Doe). Sorry for such text, cant share the actual code, so had to try out different things to reproduce the issue.

[image: In browser]

Dev tools view with borders:
[image: Dev tools view]

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/AjayPalSingh22/ahg2qyre/

I want it to have all list items in two lines

Comment: That is due to the _previous_ item, `<li style="height:17px">A</li>` By reducing the height of this, compared to the height of the other items, you are creating space for the `|` item to slide into that position. Give your li a green brackground, and this particular one a red one - then you should be able to see it. You need to remember that the actual effect of float is not so much on the floated element itself - but it specifies how the following inline content is allowed to float _around_ this element.

Comment: Looks more like a job for a flex-box

Comment: you shouldn't be using floats for layout anymore